# $arg(z) $ for negative angle ilustrated

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

so my task is to illustrate this in a coordinate system

$-(\pi/2) < arg(z-1+i) < \pi/2$

or this -(pi/2)<arg(z)<3pi/4

I know how to do it for positive angles but how can you illustrate it for negative (in this case for both positive and negative)?
Also, excuse me for not using all the fancy formating, it's my first time here on this website.

Thanks you for help.

Comment: IF $\;z=-i\;$ , your inequalities are false. Are you giving the whole information? Perhaps there is something else you're letting out about $\;z\;$ , say?

Comment: well here is another one literally from my class -(pi/2)<arg(z)<3pi/4

Comment: Well, then the task is probably to graph or describe all the set of complex $\;z\;$ s.t. $\;-\frac\pi2<\arg(z-1+i)<\frac\pi2\;$ ...?

Comment: yes, graph, but i have no idea how to graph something greater than negative pi/2, this is the problem i have. I could illustrate it if it was 0 or positive instead of negative, but with negative i don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

The set of complex numbers with argument between $\;-\cfrac\pi2\;$ and $\;\cfrac\pi2\;$ is the whole right side complex semiplane $\;H\;$. Thus, we want complex $\;z=x+iy\,,\,\,x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ , such that:

$$-\frac\pi2<\arg(z-1+i)<\frac\pi2\iff z-1+i=(x-1)+(y+1)i\in H\iff$$

$$x-1>0\iff x>1$$

You can now graph the set of complex numbers fulfilling the condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your time.